# Proper way to remember multiple parameters across requests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My application feature a "main" page where most of the action happens: There are tags for filtering and a list of results in a (paginated) table, plus the possibility to select some or all results in a "shopping cart".

This page has to keep track of a whole lot of things: what tags are selected, what items are selected, and how the result table is sorted and what page it's on. Everything has to persist, so if I select a new tag, the page must partially reload but remember everything (sorting, what's selected).

Right now I'm handling everything with parameters, and for each action taken on the page, all links (select a tag/item, change page, sort table) are updated to include previous parameters + the relevant new addition. This works, obviously, but it feels kind of inefficient, as I have to reload more of the page than I want to. How is this situation normally handled? I can't find that much info on google at all, but it doesn't feel like a particularly uncommon case.

tl;dr: How to best make sure all links (to the same page) always include everything previously selected + the new action. There are a lot of links (one per tag to select/deselect, one per result item to select/deselect, one per sort option, one per page)

Comment: Just store that data in session, read this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are five ways to do that:

#### Method 1: By parameters

You mentioned this. I never think of this as it's too troublesome. Anyway it's still a solution for very simple case.

#### Method 2: By cookie

Save the settings to a cookie and read the cookie in controller to arrange layout settings.

#### Method 3: By LocalStorage

Similar to cookie but allows more space.

#### Method 4: By Session

If you are using ActiveRecord to save session, this could be the best solution for pure pages loading. Save the user preferences into session and load it in next layout.

#### Method 5: Use Ajax

This is the best solution IMO. Instead of whole page loading, use Ajax to refresh/retrieve changes you need. Using together with above method, a user can even continue his last preferences. This is the most powerful and should be applicable to your case which looks like a web app than a website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been thinking about the Ajax option, as I'm already using ajax requests to reload only the dynamic parts of the page on each reload. However I still need to remember a whole of things which for instance affects what queries must be done. So I still need to remember for instance what tags are selected. So that when I click a second tag, the query for data is "belongs to tag 1 and to tag 2"), and if I deselect tag 1, then only "belongs to tag 2". I still need a way to store what has been selected. Would you use javascript variables for this? Store it in session?

Comment: @user2261892, yes you need JS code to handle that. Once tag selected, it triggers a JS action. The action could be either saving the selected tags to cookie/localstorage, or to trigger an Ajax request sending the preference, then the receiver of Ajax will be responsible to write the preference into session or other storage.

Comment: Thank you, this got me started and I got most of it working with the new method now. If anyone reads this and wants more help on the way, I handled it this way: Created two new controllers, one for selecting tags and one for selecting items. Each tag/item links to one of these controllers with the tag/item id as a parameter. The controller adds or removes the tag/item from the session hash and returns a js.erb template to re-render the relevant parts. I kept sorting and page as parameters. Using the cookie to store selected tags and items, although this might be too small for two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating model for all those attributes? and just always load the 'latest' when on the page load, if you dont need them you can always have a flag for that session.